# Circumferences inside equilateral

Tags: geometry

What is the maximum of disjoint circumferences that I can put into an equilateral triangle with radius $r$ and side $l$, respectively?

Any bibliography about this? Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_an_equilateral_triangle

Comment: To be clear: Do you intend to place some maximal number of *discs* of radius $r$ inside the equilateral triangle of sidelength $l,$ so that the discs do not overlap? If so does it matter if two discs meet at a point common to the bounding circles of each?

Comment: http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirintri/